# How to edit Kubernetes cluster values for OIDC?

Tags: kubernetes, openid

We are plannig to implement OpenID authentication to Kubernetes, Im finding a way to add oidc-issue-url to Kubernetes cluster as descibe here [Kubernetes OpenID](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#option-1---oidc-authenticator)

But im unable to find cluster configuration.
How can i add or edit values to Kubernetes Cluster API server using kubectl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/).

> The Kubernetes API server validates and configures data for the api objects which include pods, services, replicationcontrollers, and others. The API Server services REST operations and provides the frontend to the cluster’s shared state through which all other components interact.
>
> ```
> kube-apiserver [flags]
> ```

If using  [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops), run  `kops edit cluster`  and add:

```
spec:
  kubeAPIServer:
    oidcIssuerURL: ISSUER_URL
    oidcClientID: YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

If you are using  [kube-aws](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kube-aws), add following to  `cluster.yaml`:

```
       oidc:
         enabled: true
         issuerUrl: ISSUER_URL
         clientId: YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

You can read more about setup of on [here](https://github.com/int128/kubelogin/blob/master/docs/setup.md), you might also consider using  [Kubelogin](https://github.com/int128/kubelogin)

EDIT:

`kube-apiserver` is running as a Docker container on your master node. Therefore, the binary is within the container, not on your host system. It is started by the master's `kubelet` from a file located at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`. `kubelet` is watching this directory and will start any Pod defined here as "static pods".

To configure `kube-apiserver` command line arguments you need to modify `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` on your master.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your comment. 
im not using AWS , its a local K8s cluster with 3 worker nodes. While checking , There is no package kube-apiserver available to install. So how do i use this command . We are using CentOS 7.x .

Comment: @JamesArems, I've edited the answer to provide a bit more details.

Comment: Thank you. Now its very clear.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, modifying the manifest file at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and adding the oidc flags as found at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/ will configure oidc for your apiserver.

I'd like to add two additional items that would have been helpful for me when I came across this thread while researching issues I had while configuring oidc:

1. If you want to configure a group or user prefix with a colon, the syntax needs to look like this to avoid syntax errors when the manifest is parsed

```
    - "--oidc-groups-prefix=oidc:"
    - "--oidc-username-prefix=oidc:"
```

2. When you set --oidc-ca-file make sure the ca file you point it at exists first. If it doesn't exist the apiserver will not start and the logs are not very helpful